# Подключение шаблона к PHP.

Tags: шаблоны, php, html

Интересует вопрос как правильней и лучше реализовать подключение шаблона к php коду. Хотелось бы чтобы шаблон лежал в отдельной папке. Какими путями лучше пойти? Инклудами или как-то иначе...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Просто столкнулся с тем что если файлфайлы шаблона лежат в другой папке то при инклуде не подключаются ни фалы стилей ни картинки ни спрайты вообщем ничего. И это понятно так как пляска то идет от вызываемого файла.

Так а в чем проблема, указывайте пути абсолютные. Не `"../css/style.css"`, а `"/css/style.css"` или `"http://mysite.com/css/style.css"`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
```

Опять же, может, это вам поможет:

```
define('TPL_PATH', '/templates/');
define('TPL_PATH_FULL', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].TPL_PATH);

function wrapFile($file, $templateID) {
  if (!file_exists($file)) die('No File!');
  if (!file_exists($tpl = TPL_PATH_FULL.$templateID.'.tpl')) die('No Template');
  $TEMPLATE_DIR = TPL_PATH.$templateID.'/'; // /templates/mypage/
  ob_start();
  require $file;
  $CONTENT = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  ob_start();
  require $tpl;
  $ret = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $ret;
  }

// wrapFile(__FILE__, 'mypage')
```

А в шаблоне использовать пути

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=$TEMPLATE_DIR?>css/style.css" />
<!-- путь будет /templates/mypage/css/style.css -->
```

Comment: Спасибо буду экспериментировать)

Answer (score 0):

Вот очень интересная статья на данную тему: [Шаблонизаторы](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/30675/)

Answer (score 0):

только инклудами, если вы не хотите ппариться с разбором HTML от РНР, то можете воспользоватся шаблонизатором, но тогда ваш проект будет занимать относительно много место(что очень критично если вы пишите какой нибудь движок), но если вы таки спокойно разбираете "смешаный" код то советую просто создать файлик-темплейтер

Comment: Просто столкнулся с тем что если файл\файлы шаблона лежат в другой папке то при инклуде не подключаются ни фалы стилей ни картинки ни спрайты вообщем ничего. И это понятно так как пляска то идет от вызываемого файла. Хотел узнать существет ли простое решение (чтобы не изобретать велосипед) без подключения шаблонизаторов всяких.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fgc = file_get_contents('dir/file.html');

$fgc = str_replace('{title}','Заголовок страницы' $fgc);
$fgc = str_replace('{body}','Текст страницы' $fgc);
echo $fgc;

// file.html
<html>
<head>
<title>{title}</title>
</head>
<body>
{body}
</body>
</html>
```

Абсолютно простой пример

Answer (score -4):

а как иначе? Инклудами юзай! 
Кстати советую в качестве шаблонизатора Smarty (http://smarty.net)

Comment: Smarty конечно хорошо но не хочу загромождать свой проект этим... да и разбираться в нем не очень хочется... Интересовало как из разных папок обращаться к папке с шаблоном.